# Timer and gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to display a online user indication in image item template of gridview inside a update panel which triggers by a timer in a certain time period. The image item template is getting image from a generic handler (.ashx) using a sql server database. the gridview is getting data from another sql server table which is inside an update panel as mentioned earlier. the problem is- when i login the main page from different browser (IE, Firefox,Chrome) in same pc the first browser which i login first, it is not displaying the latest user online indication. What should i do??? Plz help me.

Comment: Do you have code to show?